# Search for row keys with spaces without space using Hbase filters

Tags: python-3.x, hbase, hbase-filter

I am trying to fetch the rows from Hbase table using RowFilter.

I have a hbase table with data as mentioned below

```
RowKey
krm south tower
krm north tower
```

If I give "krm" or "krm south" as input to the RowFilter I get the respective records.

```
RowFilter(=,'binaryprefix:krm') or RowFilter(=,'binaryprefix:krm south')
```

When I pass "krmsouth"(without spaces) to the filter, it returns me empty records.

```
RowFilter(=,'binaryprefix:krmsouth')
```

I need to get the corresponding values of krm south tower if "krmsouth" is passed to the filter. Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is that your row keys really shouldn't have spaces. If you absolutely need row keys with spaces, you'll have to write your own code that runs the query with and without spaces. Alternately you can write a Coprocessor.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. What if i need to search column values for similar scenario?

Comment: The same would apply (although of course it's perfectly acceptable to have values with spaces).